# Precedence of postfix ++

Tags: c++, operators

Consider these codes:

```
int a = 5;
int b = a++;
cout << "b is " << b << endl; // b is 5
```

or:

```
int get_number(){
    int a = 5;
    return a++;
}
int main(){
    int b = get_number();
    cout << "b is " << b << endl; // b is 5
}
```

According to [this table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) postfix `++` operator has higher precedence than `=` operator so the output should be `b is 6`. but the output is `b is 5`. How can we explain this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The contract of the postfix++ operator (and postfix-- operator) for built-in types is that it returns the *previous value*, irrespective of the change that takes place. So the function still returns `5`, even if the variable which received the change is assigned `6` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

As per [expr.post.incr](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.post#incr), **emphasis mine**:

> The value of a postfix ++ expression **is the value of its operand**. [ Note: The value obtained is a *copy of* the original value — end note ]
>
> The value computation of the ++ expression is sequenced **before** the
>   modification of the operand object. With respect to an
>   indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of postfix ++
>   is a single evaluation

```
int a = 5;
int b = a++; // the value computation for a is
             // the non-modified / non-incremented value
             // which is 5

std::cout << "a is " << a << std::endl; // a is 6
std::cout << "b is " << b << std::endl; // b is 5
```